# Application crash after changing minSdkversion to 26 on view binding

Tags: android, android-viewbinding, android-min-sdk

I am trying to create the `.aab` file from Android studio and app bundle needs minimum SDK version 26, so I changed the version in all the module `Gradle` files, and the `.aab` file got created, but after that when I tried running the app it keeps getting crashed when I load dynamic feature module and gave `- NullPointerException: binding.userName must not be null` error.when I revert it to minSdkVersionto 23, it works.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this already?

Comment: I created a slightly more detailed question on SO, but it addresses the same issue as you are most likely having: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67400780. Also check this issue on the issuetracker of google: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/123304430